# Difference between Style and Presenter?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Could you tell me what is the main difference between Style and Presenter? When or why to use one or the other?

Looking at a [sample from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates#control-template) they seem to serve exactly the same purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Style` to modify the properties of a `FrameworkElement`. A `Style` can apply to a single element or to multiple elements.

To change the font size of all `Button` elements within a certain scope to *28* and the `Border` to *Red*, you can create the following `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="28" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

But the `Button` doesn't only have properties like `BorderBrush`, `BorderThickness` or `Content`, but also an appearance. The control must somehow show a render the appearance of the property values.

This visual appearance is described by a `ControlTemplate`. It defines that there will be a `Border` and where exactly the `Border` will be and where the `Content` value is placed.

To place the content, the `ControlTemplate` of a `Button` or every other `ContentControl` contains a `ContentPresenter`. This presenter is responsible to show the data of a `ContentControl`: the `ContentControl.Content` value.

The simplest visual of a `Button` could look like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
  
        <!-- Add a Border and bind it to the Button's properties -->
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

          <!-- 
            Show the content of the Button (the value of the Content Property).
            By default the ContentPresenter of a ContentControl will automatically
            bind to the Content property
          -->
          <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
      </ContentPresenter>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

An `ItemsControl` would display items instead of simple content, the data values of the `ItemsControl.Items` property. Of course the `ItemsControl` uses a different type of presenter, as it needs to display a different data like a collection of items. But the exact same purpose: present the data.

The data of a `Button` is the `Content` e.g "Save" text.
The data of an `ItemsControl` are the individual items, the values of the `Items` property.

Beside specifying the location of the content, the presenter also applies the `DataTemplates` to the data it is showing. You use a `DataTemplate` to define the appearance of the data itself. For this purpose the `ContentControl` exposes a `ContentTemplate` property and the `ItemsControl` a `ItemTemplate` property.

I don't want to write a new documentation, so I'll stop here.
You should definitely read more about it. Since WPF and UWP follow the same concept, you can read documentation of both frameworks.

[Styles and templates in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-overview#styles)
[Control templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates#learn-more-about-a-controls-default-template)
[Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)

Answer (score 1):

These are two very different things.

A listviewitempresenter is uwp rather than wpf.

You can see the namespace here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter?view=winrt-19041

Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls means uwp.

It presents the content of a listviewitem.  It inherits from content presenter and this is perhaps a clearer way of thinking about what it is. A content presenter is a sort of place holder for content which is going to be shown.
A container of a UI thing which will be shown.

A style is a re-usable piece of markup that can apply the same values to multiple elements which it's applied to. Much like a css style. It has effect by being applied to a dependency object of some sort. Technically, this could be any dependency object but in practice will usually be a piece of UI.